# SOQL Query user

Tags: soql, rest

I am getting the following error using this REST query. I am able to successfully generate tokens and user info prior to issuing this query. I need to simply retrieve the salesforce userid based on the email address of the user.

> > ERROR [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
> >     curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 00D2C0000000nwB!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -H X-PrettyPrint

```
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+id,name,profile.name+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

- OR -

```
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+id+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on a Mac or Linux OS I believe that you need to add '\' in your Bearer:

**This:**

```
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+id,name,profile.name+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

**To this:**

```
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+id,name,profile.name+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB\!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

Notice the backslash between **00D2C0000000nwB** and **!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**

**UPDATED:**

try to add the  `-H "Authorization:Beare token"` like this:

```
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+id,name,profile.name+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB\!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Also, try using a '**/**' rigth after **query**.

Give it a try.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I'm just running curl on a win 10 Command line. Ran and got this error:   (6) Could not resolve host: 00D2C0000000nwB\!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -H X-PrettyPrint - when running
curl https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/qu ery?q=SELECT+id,name,profile.name+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com.partial1 Bearer 00D2C0000000nwB\!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"

Comment: If you are using Windows OS you don't need to add the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

All comes down to syntax when using good old command line interface. Note I needed to include the -H Authorization to make the token believable. This works now.

```
curl https://maiden.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+id,name,email+FROM+user+WHERE+username='myemail@xxx.com' -H "Authorization: Bearer 00DG0000000jAvp!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```